# Hourly GIT Push

Tags: command-line, cron, git, scripts

Is it possible for me to automate a [Git](http://git-scm.com/) push every hour via a batch script.

I would typically type in this:

```
git add *
git commit -m "latest update"
git push https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git master
```

How can I automate this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, you can do this with cron. To add a task to cron, you need to run

```
crontab -e
```

The syntax should be specified in a comment on the last line, but I'll explain it anyway:

m h  dom mon dow   command
In order: these are the minute, hour, date-of-month, month, day-of-week, and the command to run at this time.

So, to run it every hour, you would want:

```
0 * * * * /home/username/bin/git-backup-script.sh
```

Which means to run the script on the 0th minute of every hour of every day etc.

Where /home/username/bin/git-backup-script.sh is a shell script that does everything that you mentioned (though don't forget to cd to the relevant directory in it!)

Comment: Edited script to solve problem. Listed in question, thanks for the Cron help!

Comment: Oh, sweet, I didn't know you could put the Github auth in like that with Git - nice! :)

Comment: That method uses the relatively unknown http username and password parameters, not used by many sites.

E.G.:  `username:password@example.com`

Comment: Yeah, I'd known that you could do HTTP auth like that, it just didn't occur to me that you could use it for Github for some reason. Cool!

Comment: That works the same for most online git services using HTTP.